# STM32 HAL Implementing UART receive Interrupt

Tags: stm32, hal-library

I have trouble in implementing the USART RX on a stm32f303k8t6 with the HAL libraries. What I actually want to achieve is, that I can send a variable length string over the uart bus and decode the string, which is actually a key/value pair. What I have tried so far is the following: I receive an interrupt for every received character and as long it is not a '$' sign, it is loading a buffer. But somehow the interrupt function is only called once, and I don't get why. I would anyway like to use the callback functions from HAL, but they never get called.

*stm32f3xx_it.c*

```c
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 0 */
    if (USART1->ISR & UART_IT_RXNE) {
        isRx = 1;
    }

    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */
    if (isRx) {
        uint8_t rbyte = huart1.Instance->RDR;
        __HAL_UART_SEND_REQ(&huart1, UART_RXDATA_FLUSH_REQUEST);
        rx_data[pointer] = rbyte;
        if (rx_data[pointer] == '$') {
            rx_data[pointer] = '\0';
            pointer = 0;
            copyValuesToBuff();
            clearBuffer(&rx_data,32);
        } else {
            pointer++;
            if(pointer >= 32) {
                pointer = 0;
            }
        }
        __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1,UART_IT_RXNE);
    }
}
```

*main.c*

```c
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "USART.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
char rx_buff[32];
char rx_data[32];
/* USER CODE END PV */
uint8_t aRxBuffer[10];
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    //__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1,UART_IT_RXNE);
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 10);
    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }

    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
    */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks
    */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                 |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
    PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
    if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time
    */
    HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick
    */
    HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

    /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 57600;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}

/** Pinout Configuration
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
* @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
* @param  None
* @retval None
*/
void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    while (1)
    {
    }

    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
* @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
* where the assert_param error has occurred.
* @param file: pointer to the source file name
* @param line: assert_param error line source number
* @retval None
*/
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
    /* USER CODE END 6 */
}

#endif
```

Comment: first of all try tu implement the parsing function without any interrupts and uarts. To be honest I cant read your code.  When you will able to parse the input , try to receive it via uart. When both parts work - connect them.

Comment: You say that you receive data but what hw is sending the data? It should be possible to understand if the sender does not send or if the receiver is not receiving. I think that is first step in troubleshoot if you did not do this already.

Comment: you should also show the UART cubemx configuration , a screen shot might be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

With a quick glance I see two potential issues.
1. You need to put the HAL_UART_Receive_ITinside the super loop.
2. The IRQ handler needs to be kept short. What you want to do is put the code in the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback function which is going to be run after every RX.

It is a good idea to just try to use some the STM32 Cube examples.

Comment: I know that the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback should be run after every RX, but it does not, so I had to try a fix somehow. I really don't understand why it is not called, since I receive the data correctly with my method. Is there any known bug for the CubeMX 4.22.1 for the STM32F303K8T6?